Custom library repository artifacts not imported
Sonatype nexus not importing custom project artifacts upon maven clean install.
In Sonatype Nexus, I have created following three repositories:
    1. my-proxy-repo(proxy)
    2. my-parent-repo(hosted)
    3. my-group-repo(group)

So basically (1) is a proxy repository I created in Nexus which points to maven-central and idea is to download all artifacts upon maven install.
proxy repository
Repository (2) my-parent-repo is a hosted repository and the parent repository or custom libraries jar which I have created and intend to call and use it in external spring project.
Repository (3) is a group repository which is having both of the above repositories selected. Idea is that I will use this repository to set in my settings.xml under  and also  tag so that all artifacts from (1) & (2) are downloaded locally in maven.
In the settings.xml, I have pointed to above group repository for mirrors, repository and pluginrepository.
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>gels-nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://192.168.64.130:8081/repository/my-group-repo/</url>
</mirror>
</mirrors>

    <profile>
      <id>gels-nexus</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>gels-nexus</id>
          <url>http://192.168.64.130:8081/repository/my-group-repo/</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>gels-nexus</id>
          <url>http://192.168.64.130:8081/repository/my-group-repo/</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>

I have created a new spring maven project -> ran "mvn clean install".
I expected all the artifacts from both repository (1) & (2) to be downloaded locally and present under repository folder in .m2 folder.
Issue - Only the proxy repository artifacts pointing to maven-central are downloaded and custom library repository artifacts are not downloaded at all. Tried several steps to debug issue but still unable to import repository (2) artifacts to the project.
Is anyone aware of any missing setup/configuration that is leading to this, then please leave your answer here. Thanks in advance for your efforts.

That means you would like to publish artifacts into Nexus? If so you have to use mvn deploy and not mvn install...And is required is to have a distributionManagement (https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management) to define the target

No in this case dont need to modify pom.xml with anything is what my understanding. DistributionManagement comes into scene when I have to deploy something to Nexus. My scenario is different, I am trying to access from Nexus repository, please read again

custom library repository artifacts are not downloaded? have you configure the other repositories in your nexus configuration ?

Not sure if your read well. There are 3 repos that are configured in manner described above

The my-group-repo(group) should contain the other two repos in your nexus configuration... and the first should be my-parent-repo(hosted) and the last one my-proxy-repo...

I have maintained it the exact way in nexus. But still during build of project, it will only retrieve artifacts from proxy repo alone and nothing from parent repo!! Any idea what is missing?
